# Data is not loaded in BI Publisher flash template - Error #2032

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, flash-builder, bi-publisher

I have created a simple reprot with one level of XML data, and followed all the guide lines from oracle tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10383_01/doc/bip.1013/e10416/flashtemp.htm

When I run the application from Flash Builder, it works fine, a simple data grid as in the tutorial
But when I upload the swf file to the flash template in publisher, it fails to run with error#2032, I've searched and searched for any clue of what is wrong! no tutorial or help was useful.

Here is my flex application source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var dataXML:XML = 
                <ROWSET>
                <ROW>
                <ACCOUNT_NUMBER>999222111</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
                <CURR_CODE>USD</CURR_CODE>
                <INSTALLMENT_AMOUNT_LC>8840</INSTALLMENT_AMOUNT_LC>
                </ROW>
                </ROWSET>;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Panel left="10" top="10" width="477" height="267" layout="absolute">
        <mx:DataGrid left="0" right="1" top="0" bottom="10" dataProvider="{dataXML.ROW}"
                     horizontalCenter="-1">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ACCOUNT_NUMBER" headerText="Account Number"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="CURR_CODE" headerText="Currency Code"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="INSTALLMENT_AMOUNT_LC" headerText="Instalment Amount"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:Panel>
```

I don't know whats wrong with the code! or what is causing the error, BI or the swf file.

Can anyone help me ?

I use Oracle 10g, and Flash builder 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search, I came to the result that there is **no solution for linking reports built using Flex Builder 4.6 with Oracle 10g BI Publisher** that I'm aware of.

But when I downgraded to Flex Builder 2.0, it worked for me, and I'm now able to see the data in the flash template that is built using this version of Flex when the report runs in Oracle BI Publisher and without changing any code from the above question.

I believe this is backward compatibility issue between Oracle 10g and its BI Publisher, and the new versions of the Flex Builder from Adobe.